# Пожалуйста подскажите плагины для Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, плагин

Я создаю сайт для клиента, он не знает ничего в html и php поэтому есть такой вопрос.
В шапке сайта есть контакты их нужно редактировать клиенту. Как это реализовать и какой плагин при этом использовать?

Попробовал плагин [Custom Options Plus](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/custom-options-plus/), но дело в том что там только поле `textarea`. В котором я написал таким образом:

```
+7-(777)-777-77-77<br>+7-(777)-777-77-77
```

Но хотелось бы что бы было поле input в котором написано так:

> Рабочий номер `input`
>   Мобильный номер `input`

Надеюсь я объяснил понятно

Answer (score 0):

Один из простых вариантов - в этой области [шаблона](https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%98%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%85%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2) темы ([дочерней](https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%94%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B), чтобы не потерять возможности обновления) поместить [сайдбар](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_sidebar). В него вставить текстовый виджет, где клиент сможет менять что хочет.

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете использовать плагин ACF - https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/
Создайте поле или несколько полей под контакты для главной страницы, например. Т.е. клиент заходя в админке в редактирование главной страници сможет там менять нужные контакты.

В файле шапки (или где у вас нужно вывести контакты) поставьте:

`<?php echo get_field('field_name', $page_id); ?>`
- где:

**field_name** - это имя поле (заданное в настройках плагина)

**$page_id** - ID-главной страницы